# How update and remove redux state reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, updates

When I move a user I would like to update new group the reducer and remove user in old groups

```
/mystate
// groups: [
//   {
//     users: [
//       '1A',
//       '1B'
//     ],
//     id: '2',
//     name: 'shoes'
//   },
//   {
//     users: [],
//     id: '1',
//     name: 't-shirt'
//   }
// ]
```

My reducer show this and i don't know how to update groups the data

````
  //in action get id groups and group with id users
  // {
  //   type: 'UPDATE_GROUP',
  //   id: '1A',
  //   group: [
  //     '1'
  //   ]
  // }
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_GROUP:
      return {
        ...state,
        shop: {
          ...state.shop,
          groups: state.shop.groups ????
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}```
````